# Maven pom.xml autocomplete not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, autocomplete, pom.xml

I can't seem to get Eclipse to autocomplete anything in my pom.xml file in a Maven project.  I haven't created a Maven project in some time but I remember adding a junit dependency and having Eclipse autocomplete the version.  I just don't get any options anymore.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is my recollection too. Eclipse and autocompletion is quite poor in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure which part did the trick but the following settings are working for me in Eclipse Kepler.

Go to: Preferences -> Maven
Check the checkboxes 'Download repository index updates on startup' and 'Update Maven projects on startup'

Go to: Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings
Check if in the value in field 'User Settings' point to an vallid 'settings.xml'
Press 'update settings'
(In my case the maven settings.xml file is not at the default Eclipse location)

Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

First would be, do you have the m2e eclipse installed? that's in "About Eclipse"/plugins in I recall...

Second would be, does the project has a Maven nature ? do you need the Maven contextual menus when you right click on the project ?

Third would be, what editor are you using to open pom.xml -> you can validate this by going into preferences/file associations. or by right clicking on the pom.xml and selecting "open with"

Comment: Yes I have m2eclipse installed.  And I'm using the plain xml editor but I have similar issues using the m2eclipse POM editor.

Comment: well if maven completion there is, you would expect it to work from the pom editor. what completion features are you thinking about ? mine works fine, it auto closes tags, ctrl/command + space shows completion